# NFS 'no_wdelay' export option not being applied

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs, nfsv4

I have an NFS server configured and its up and running without an issue. But I need to enable the `no_wdelay` option on the exports. I have modified the `/etc/exports` file to be as following(added `no_wdelay` option):

```
/exports 10.0.3.10/8(rw,sync,no_subtree_check,all_squash,no_wdelay)
```

So I want to apply the above changes to the nfs server. I have tried the following commands.

1. `sudo exportfs -ra`
2. `sudo systemctl try-restart nfs-config.service rpcbind.service rpc-statd.service nfs-server.service`
3. `sudo systemctl restart nfs-server`
4. `sudo service nfs-kernel-server restart`
5. `sudo service nfs-server restart`
6. `sudo /etc/init.d/nfs-kernel-server restart`

But when I check the status using `sudo /usr/sbin/exportfs -v` or `exportfs -v` it gives the output which doesn't have the `no_wdelay` option:

```
/exports    10.0.3.10/8(rw,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,sec=sys,rw,root_squash,all_squash)
```

The content of `/var/lib/nfs/etab` shows that `no_wdelay` option is there:

```
/exports 10.0.3.10/8(rw,sync,no_wdelay,hide,nocrossmnt,secure,root_squash,all_squash,no_subtree_check,secure_locks,acl,anonuid=65534,anongid=65534,sec=sys,rw,root_squash,all_squash)
```

What am I doing wrong ? Is the option getting applied or not ? What is the correct way to check this ?

System Info:

```
uname -a
Linux nfs-server 4.13.0-1012-gcp #16-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 15 12:00:42 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Have you remounted the file system on the client?

Comment: @RamanSailopal No I havent, do I need to remount it ? I couldnt find any reference where remounting is required.

Comment: It's worth a try? Even on a test setup